# 3 forks and 6 pipes

Tags: c, fork

I'm writing my first fork-pipe code in order to learn how it works.

The point is that I want to create 3 children that will communicate with his dad and each child will perform different tasks.

This is the code I'm working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nbytes;
    int     fd1[2], fd11[2]; /*fd1-->child1*/
    int     fd2[2], fd21[2]; /*fd2-->child2*/
    int     fd3[2], fd31[2]; /*fd3-->child3*/
    pid_t   child1, child2, child3;
    char    string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
    char    string1[] = "Shutting Down\n";
    char    readbuffer[80];

    printf("child1-->%d\n", child1);
    if (child1==0 && child2==0 && child3==0){

        printf( "   HOLA-> pid %d\n", getpid() );

        if(pipe(fd1)==-1 || pipe(fd11)==-1){ //Creating Pipes for son 1
            perror("pipe");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(pipe(fd2)==-1 || pipe(fd21)==-1){ //Creating Pipes for son 2
            perror("pipe");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if(pipe(fd3)==-1 || pipe(fd31)==-1){ //Creating Pipes for son 3
            perror("pipe");
            exit(-1);
        }

        if((child1 = fork()) == -1){
            perror("fork");
            exit(-1);
        }

        /*Creating child 2 and 3*/
        if((child2 = fork()) == -1){
            perror("fork");
            exit(-1);
        }
        if((child3 = fork()) == -1){
            perror("fork");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    if(child1==0){ // Child 1

        close(fd2[0]);close(fd21[0]);close(fd3[0]);close(fd31[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);close(fd21[1]);close(fd3[1]);close(fd31[1]);
        close(fd1[1]); /* Son process closes up output side of pipe */
        close(fd11[0]); /* Son process closes up input side of pipe */

        /* Read in a string from the pipe */
        read(fd1[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("I'm SON1 -->Received string: %s\n", readbuffer);

        printf("LOADING...\n");         
        sleep(2);

        write(fd11[1], "SON1-->Shutting Down\n", (strlen("SON1-->Shutting Down\n")+1));
        printf("I'm SON1 -->send string & shutdown\n");

        exit(0);

    }else if(child2==0){ // Child 2

        close(fd1[0]);close(fd11[0]);close(fd3[0]);close(fd31[0]);
        close(fd1[1]);close(fd11[1]);close(fd3[1]);close(fd31[1]);
        close(fd2[1]); /* Son process closes up output side of pipe */
        close(fd21[0]); /* Son process closes up input side of pipe */

        /* Read in a string from the pipe */
        read(fd2[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("I'm SON2 -->Received string: %s\n", readbuffer);

        printf("LOADING...\n");         
        sleep(2);

        write(fd21[1], "SON2-->Shutting Down\n", (strlen("SON2-->Shutting Down\n")+1));
        printf("I'm SON2 -->send string & shutdown\n");

        exit(0);    

    }else if(child3==0){ // Child 3

        close(fd2[0]);close(fd21[0]);close(fd1[0]);close(fd11[0]);
        close(fd2[1]);close(fd21[1]);close(fd1[1]);close(fd11[1]);
        close(fd3[1]); /* Son process closes up output side of pipe */
        close(fd31[0]); /* Son process closes up input side of pipe */

        /* Read in a string from the pipe */
        read(fd3[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("I'm SON3 -->Received string: %s\n", readbuffer);

        printf("LOADING...\n");         
        sleep(2);

        write(fd31[1], "SON3-->Shutting Down\n", (strlen("SON3-->Shutting Down\n")+1));
        printf("I'm SON3 -->send string & shutdown\n");

        exit(0);    

    }else{ // DAD Code      

        close(fd1[0]);close(fd2[0]);close(fd3[0]); /* Father process closes up input side of pipe */
        close(fd11[1]);close(fd21[1]);close(fd31[1]); /* Father process closes up output side of pipe */

        /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
        write(fd1[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
        printf("I'm the father -->send string to SON1\n");

        write(fd2[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
        printf("I'm the father -->send string to SON2\n");

        write(fd3[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
        printf("I'm the father -->send string to SON3\n");

        read(fd11[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("I'm the father -->SON1 Received string: %s", readbuffer);

        read(fd21[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("I'm the father -->SON2 Received string: %s", readbuffer);

        read(fd31[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("I'm the father -->SON3 Received string: %s", readbuffer);

        sleep(2);
        printf("Father shutting down\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

My problem is that when I execute the code, it appears something like that:

```
I'm the father -->send string to SON1
I'm the father -->send string to SON2
I'm the father -->send string to SON3
I'm SON3 -->Received string: Hello, world!

LOADING...
I'm SON2 -->Received string: Hello, world!

LOADING...
I'm SON1 -->Received string: Hello, world!

LOADING...
I'm SON3 -->send string & shutdown
I'm SON2 -->send string & shutdown
I'm SON1 -->send string & shutdown
I'm the father -->SON1 Received string: SON1-->Shutting Down
I'm the father -->SON2 Received string: SON2-->Shutting Down
I'm the father -->SON3 Received string: SON3-->Shutting Down
Father shutting down

V:~$ I'm SON2 -->Received string: 
LOADING...
I'm SON1 -->Received string: 
LOADING...
I'm SON1 -->Received string: 
LOADING...
I'm SON1 -->Received string: 
LOADING...
```

My question is: Where the four calls to the sons come from? What am I missing?

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are two different languages.  The C++ language has support for threads.  The C++ language has `std::string` and C doesn't.

Comment: Which platform?  The standard C language doesn't have support for threading, as it is a platform specific issue.

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, [The Fork Bomb.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)

Comment: Not all that useful but gosh darn amusing! :(){ :|:& };:

Comment: @user4581301 aren't today's operating systems designed to split the time epoch between parent and son process to prevent such scenarios ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I got it now. Your mistake is that you are forking the following way:

```
if ((child1 = fork() == -1) {
   // handle error
}

if ((child2 = fork()) == -1)
..
..
..
```

After fork, a new process copy is created. It will continue from same position as the parent. It will also execute the next fork
After first fork, a new child is created. Then after second fork you will have 4 processes which will execute the 3rd fork. Ending up with 8 processes. Assuming fork sys call didn't fail.

If you want to create only 3 processes then it should be this way:

```
Child1 = fork();
if (Child1 == -1) { // handle error }
if (Child1 == 0) { // child process }
if (Child1 > 0) 
{ 
    Child2 = fork();
    if (Child2 == -1) ...
    if (child2 == 0)...
    if (child2 > 0)
    {
       Child3 = fork();....
    }
  .
  .
```

Answer (score 5):

Lets just look at this code:

```
    if((child1 = fork()) == -1){
        perror("fork");
        exit(-1);
    }
    /*Creating child 2 and 3*/
    if((child2 = fork()) == -1){
        perror("fork");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if((child3 = fork()) == -1){
        perror("fork");
        exit(-1);
    }
```

Assuming none of the forks fail, after the first fork, you'll have two processes (parent and child) both of which continue from that point.  So both will execute the second fork, giving you 4 processes (parent, 2 children, and grandchild) all of which proceed to the 3rd fork, after which you have 8 processes...